# ショートカットキーのコピーがうまく機能しない

Tags: vscode

'⌘＋C'のショートカットキーを使用すると本文自体はコピー出来ますが、その後、選択モード？の様なものになってバックスペースボタンを押すと後ろに戻ったり、Enterを押しても行の挿入がされず下の行に行ったりします。
英数のaボタンを連打していると直りますが、'⌘＋C'を押すとまた同じ様な現象になります。こちらをコピーだけにするにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？